# Get Ids of terminated EC2 instances

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to create a report about our EC2 instances usage and utilization over time. I would like to examine all of the instance that have or had been running in my environment for the past X days. As part of the report I would like to include instances that were created during a scale-group scale out but later were terminated as the group scaled in.

Using a simple python script with `boto3` I can get the list of instances for a region:

```
session = Session(aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, region_name=self.name)
ec2 = session.resource('ec2')
cloudwatch = session.resource('cloudwatch')
```

By listing the instances, using the following command, I do not see terminated instances after a few hours (probably the same time you stop seeing them in the dashboard):

```
ec2.instances.all()
```

Using cloudwatch, when I use the following command, I do see the metrics for terminated instances:

```
metric = cloudwatch.Metric('AWS/EC2', 'CPUUtilization')
result = metric.get_statistics(
Dimensions=[{'Name': 'InstanceId', 'Value': instanceId}],
        StartTime=timeRange.start,
        EndTime=timeRange.end,
        Period=300,
        Statistics=['Average'],
) # This returns a complete list of data points for the instance was live
```

It means the metrics do exist for terminated instances but you have to have the id of those instances in order to retrieve them. **Is there a way to retrieve terminated instances ids?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unless you have CloudTrail enabled. You can get the information you want for the last 7 days from CloudTrail dashboard. If you need information older than 7 days, then get the files from the S3 bucket (if you have configured).

CloudTrail periodically stores your activity as objects in your bucket - check your CloudTrail configuration for the bucket name. The data is stored as compressed json files for each day. Write a simple Python script to download the files for the day you want and load the json file one by one, look for `TerminatedInstances` event. For each terminated instance, it will have information like instanceid, who terminated it, from where, when etc.,

Code snippet:

```
for event in events:
    if event['eventName'] == 'TerminateInstances':
        inst_ids = [item['instanceId'] for item in event['requestParameters']['instancesSet']['items']]
        print 'Terminated instance IDs:', inst_ids
```

Comment: Thanks helloV. I've never used CloudTrail before and I see it logs API calls. Does it include calls by AWS? Specifically - actions that took place automatically due to scale-up/down policies?

Comment: Yes. All APIs. I use it extensively.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **instance-state-name**:

> The state of the instance (pending | running | shutting-down |
> terminated | stopping | stopped ).

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
reservations = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=[
    {
        "Name": "instance-state-name",
        "Values": ["terminated"],
    }
]).get("Reservations")

for reservation in reservations:
    for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
        instance_id = instance["InstanceId"]
```